# Adding columns of different length into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe detailing money awarded to people over several years:

```
Name -- Money -- Year
Paul    57.00    2012
Susan   67.00    2012
Gary    54.00    2011
Paul    77.00    2011
Andrea  20.00    2011
Albert  23.00    2011
Hal     26.00    2010
Paul    23.00    2010
```

From this dataframe, I want to construct a dataframe that details all the money awarded in a single year, for making a boxplot:

```
2012 -- 2011 -- 2010
57.00   54.00   26.00
67.00   77.00   23.00
        20.00
        23.00
```

So you see this results in columns of different length. When I try to do this using pandas, I get the error `'ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index'.` I assume this is because I can't add varying length columns to a dataframe.

Can anyone offer some advice on how to proceed? Perhap I'm approaching this incorrectly? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you show the code how you are trying to do this (and that produces the error)? The rest of the column should be filled with NaNs.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just use the pandas boxplot method? `df.boxplot(by='Year')`

Comment: @TomAugspurger, you're the best. I did not know that was possible.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this in a two-step process: first add a column corresponding to the index in each year using `cumcount`, and then `pivot` so that the new column is the index, the years become the columns, and the money column becomes the values:

```
df["yindex"] = df.groupby("Year").cumcount()
new_df = df.pivot(index="yindex", columns="Year", values="Money")
```

---

For example:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("money.txt", sep="\s+")
>>> df
     Name  Money  Year
0    Paul     57  2012
1   Susan     67  2012
2    Gary     54  2011
3    Paul     77  2011
4  Andrea     20  2011
5  Albert     23  2011
6     Hal     26  2010
7    Paul     23  2010
>>> df["yindex"] = df.groupby("Year").cumcount()
>>> df
     Name  Money  Year  yindex
0    Paul     57  2012       0
1   Susan     67  2012       1
2    Gary     54  2011       0
3    Paul     77  2011       1
4  Andrea     20  2011       2
5  Albert     23  2011       3
6     Hal     26  2010       0
7    Paul     23  2010       1
>>> df.pivot(index="yindex", columns="Year", values="Money")
Year    2010  2011  2012
yindex                  
0         26    54    57
1         23    77    67
2        NaN    20   NaN
3        NaN    23   NaN
```

After which you could get rid of the NaNs if you like, but it depends on whether you want to distinguish between cases like "knowing the value is 0" and "not knowing what the value is":

```
>>> df.pivot(index="yindex", columns="Year", values="Money").fillna(0)
Year    2010  2011  2012
yindex                  
0         26    54    57
1         23    77    67
2          0    20     0
3          0    23     0
```

Comment: Although this works, I went with TomAugspurger's solution as it was simpler. But I learned something new from your response, so thank you!

Comment: Awesome response! Thank you for introducing the dataframe pivot operation --- I guess I should start to RTFM, but SO turns out to be easier and faster in 95% of all cases.